# Using Taylor Theorem to Estimate Error Using Approximation

Tags: calculus, approximation, error-propagation

Taylors theorem tells us that:

En(x) ≤ $\frac {M}{(n+1)!}|x-a|^n$ $^+$ $^1$

Use this to estimate the error in using the approximation.

$sin(x) ≈ x$ - $\frac {x^3}{3!}$ on the interval [-1,1]

Assuming x and a are endpoints. Does endpoint mean the interval? So x and a are -1 and 1 respectively?

M is supposed to be the upper bound.

Also I am unsure of what n is supposed to be.

How do you choose a suitable n value? Also how do you find M?

Comment: Any reason you want to use that to estimate the error? The alternation series remainder says that the error is always less than or equal to the next neglected term. Are you trying to use Lagrange Error Bound?

Comment: $n$ is the $n$th term in the Taylor polynomial. $M$ is the max of the function on the interval, which is 1.

Comment: Yes but don’t I need a specific n value to solve this inequality?

Answer (score 0):

$$ E_4(x) \le \frac {M}{(4+1)!}|x-a|^5 = \frac {1}{120}(1)^5 = 1/120$$

Note that since the coefficient of $x^4$ is $0$, the error term is $E_4.$

Comment: how did you choose 4 ?

Comment: The fourth term is zero so the given polynomial is the same as the fourth degree polynomial.

Comment: What do you mean by the fourth term is 0? Which term?

Comment: Also why have you assumed a=0 here?

Comment: From $(x-a)^n = x^n$ it is evident that the center is $a=0$

Comment: I just do not understand what made you choose 4 specifically. can you explain the logic of this decision?

Comment: $x-\frac {x^3}{3!}$ is the third degree Taylor polynomial for sin(x) but since  f(x) = sin(x) is an odd function and its fourth derivative is zero, the fourth degree polynomial is the same as the third degree polynomial.